selenium.webdriver.Firefox not working properly on the login page of nbc.com
I'm using this to auto login on nbc.com, and nbc.com login page is responding with Sorry, we had a problem. Please try again. instead of redirecting to the link provider page. Other than that the page is successfully login me into the site. I'm wandering if this is something in the source of the site that could be causing this to happen or if it is something I'm missing.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# created this class to use a profile and create it if doesn't exist
from library import Firefox

firefox = Firefox()
firefox.get('https://www.nbc.com/sign-in')

html = firefox.find_element(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'html')
form = html.find_element(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'form')

for element in form.find_elements(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'input'):
    if element.get_attribute(name = 'type') == 'email':
        element.send_keys('name@gmail.com')
    elif element.get_attribute(name = 'type') == 'password':
        element.send_keys('******')  # noqa

for element in form.find_elements(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'label'):
    if element.get_attribute(name = 'class') == 'auth-terms__terms-checkbox':  # noqa
        element.click()
        break

form.find_element(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'button').click()

I used the following code to load firefox and logged in manually and I got the same error.
from library import Firefox

firefox = Firefox()
firefox.get('https://www.nbc.com/sign-in')

I also used this to load firefox without a profile and still got the same error.
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

firefox = Firefox()
firefox.get('https://www.nbc.com/sign-in')


There is a a list of link that have to be followed to avoid the error. From the main page I clicked on the Sign Up link, then the Log In link from the signup page that took me to the login form. After logging in it took me to the right page to either skip or link my provider. This is session or cookie error being generated from the site, but I got round it in my code.

Loading time: Ensure elements have loaded before interaction.You can use
WebDriverWait

along with expected_conditions to wait for elements to load before interacting with them.

sometimes Cookies/sessions  might be required for login.


Beforehand check the correct credentials.

